# Android Studio 3.0.1-Theme Editor Buggy

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.0

This is how my theme editor looks like right now

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/J8IuT.jpg]

Everything looks like it hasn't been rendered properly. Someone else posted the same problem but it was unanswered. Anyone has a solution to this?

And changes I make from the theme editor are not reflected in the styles.xml.

Comment: You should report a bug [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/report-bugs.html).

Answer (score 0):

Change your android version on your designer preview into your current version depend on your Manifest. rendering problem caused your designer preview used higher API level than your current android API level.

You can change like Api level from here.

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ihdNv.png]

Comment: This wasn't what I asked. The preview here is fine. Only the theme editor has problems. And only changes made from the theme editor aren't showing up in the styles.xml. 
And as you can see from the screenshot,the theme editor has problems.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone was wondering,updating it 3.1.x fixes it.

Comment: Got same problem on 3.1.4, so, no. Maybe it's reinstalling that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Go to File and select invalidate cache and restart.It fixed my issue hope it fixes yours too